# Maven install-file not effective in GitLab/Docker: "could not resolve dependencies for project"

Tags: java, maven, docker, gitlab

I'm trying to build my java project on a GitLab server using Maven in Docker. Because I use 3rd party jars, I install them locally using the install-file plugin. This is/seems succesfull both on my local machine, as on the Docker:

```
$ mvn install:install-file -Dfile=lib/customArtifact-1.0.jar -DgroupId=customArtifact -DartifactId=customArtifact -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myProject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ myProject ---
[INFO] Installing /builds/gitlab/myProject-groep/myProject/lib/customArtifact-1.0.jar to /root/.m2/repository/customArtifact/customArtifact/1.0/customArtifact-1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing /tmp/mvninstall2011198835315637645.pom to /root/.m2/repository/customArtifact/customArtifact/1.0/customArtifact-1.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.191 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-10T07:35:47+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/144M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But on the Docker I get this error, which is absent on my local machine:

```
$ mvn --batch-mode --quiet clean install -DskipTests
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myProject: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project groupId:myProject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to 
collect dependencies at customArtifact:customArtifact:jar:1.0: Failed 
to read artifact descriptor for customArtifact:customArtifact:jar:1.0:
     Could not transfer artifact customArtifact:customArtifact:pom:1.0
      from/to myProject_dependencies (/builds/gitlab/myProject-groep/
      myProject/lib): Cannot access /builds/gitlab/myProject-groep/
      myProject/lib with type default using the available connector 
      factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access 
      /builds/gitlab/myProject-groep/myProject/lib using the registered
      transporter factories: WagonTransporterFactory: Unsupported 
      transport protocol -> [Help 1]
```

I really don't get what is wrong here. Am I missing something in my path, environmental variable? It should be something minor, as I'm literally doing the same locally.

Help is much appreciated!

**EDIT**:

I'm using this Docker [maven:3-jdk-7](https://github.com/carlossg/docker-maven/blob/33eeccbb0ce15440f5ccebcd87040c6be2bf9e91/jdk-7/Dockerfile),

```
  FROM openjdk:7-jdk

  ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.3.9
  ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"

  RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
    && curl -fsSL http://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/$MAVEN_VERSION/binaries/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz \
      | tar -xzC /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
    && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

  ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
  ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

  COPY mvn-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh
  COPY settings-docker.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/

  VOLUME "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

  ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh"]
  CMD ["mvn"]which is found here
```

settings-docker.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>/usr/share/maven/ref/repository</localRepository>
</settings>
```

Comment: What is your Maven version?

Comment: The version is: Apache Maven 3.3.9

Comment: Can you share maven `settings.xml` and `Dockerfile` please? It seems that you are trying to read the dependency from a wrong path or the volume is not exposed to docker

Comment: OK, I edited the question.

Comment: from the example `localRepository` in `settings-docker.xml` is set `/usr/share/maven/ref/repository` ? did you change that? I see that maven is  looking in `/builds/gitlab/myProject-groep/myProject/lib`

Comment: Well, I have this part in my pom.xml . Maybe this messes up some path? 

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>myProject_dependencies</id>
            <url>${basedir}/lib/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>`

Comment: This is what's causing the issue `/builds/gitlab/myProject-groep/myProject/lib`  is not exposed to docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Localy**

Installing thrid-party libraries using `mvn install:install-file` will install them by default in /.m2/repository. Then `mvn clean install` will pick them from default repository i.e /.m2/repository.

**In docker container**

Installing thrid-party libraries using `mvn install:install-file` will install them in `/usr/share/maven/ref/repository` (inside the container) as defined in settings-docker.xml. Then `mvn clean install` will pick them from `/usr/share/maven/ref/repository`.

The issue is that maven is looking for dependencies in `/builds/gitlab/myProject-groep/myProject/lib` as defined in pom file, but this directory is not exposed to docker container.

```
<repositories>
    <repository> 
        <id>myProject_dependencies</id>
        <url>${basedir}/lib/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Removing repositories section from pom file should resolve the issue.